# ToggleButton redesign, can't find Property 'IsChecked'

Tags: wpf, templates, styles, togglebutton

I want to redesign my ToggleButton. I create the ToggleButton in xaml:

```
<ToggleButton Width="15" Grid.Column="2" />
```

And have the ToggleButton Style in the Resources:

```
<Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Path Name="Arrow" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" />   
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Data" Value="M 0 4 L 4 0 L 8 4 Z" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>                     
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When I'm try to build i've got this error:

> Cannot find the Template Property 'IsChecked' on the type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Control'.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give `ControlTemplate` the `TargetType` too

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
```